# How to include additional ES6 sources in Angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, ecmascript-6, angular-cli, uglifyjs

I have a custom mode module written in ES6 syntax that I am including in my angular application and I am encountering problems (from uglifyjs) when I attempt to build the app with the `-prod` flag enabled:

```
Unexpected token: punc ()
```

This is an angular 5 app using angular-cli 1.7.4 also.

The entry file for my node module is as follows:

```
const MyModule = require('./src/index.js');

const myModule = new MyModule();

module.exports = {
  doStuff: myModule.doStuff,
  doOtherStuff: myModule.doOtherStuff
}
```

This then gets required into one of my ts files like so:

```
import MyModule = require('@acme/mymodule');
```

When running the `ng serve` task, I have no problems and can use the application as expected.

Its when trying to produce a production build that I see this issue.

Within the ./src/index.js file for there are many functions defined that use const\let\async\await.

Reading around, I believe this is down to me using ES6 and the sources not being compatible with uglifyjs under the hood when the angular cli performs the build steps.

From what I also have read, webpack configuration can be controlled from the angular-cli config, at least not in 1.x, otherwise I would have tried one of the many plugins out there to help me get around this.

I am assuming I need to be running the code through an extra step before it hits angular-cli, e.g, use babel to transform my es6 code.

I'm struggling to find examples of how to do this in relation to angular and the cli, I can find how to use babel and have been able to test this on one of my node module sources and can see the es5 version of this produced.

I actually have 4 node modules and some of these require each other, so I want to make sure they can still require in each other after being transpiled.

BTW way, not sure how relevant it is but the following polyfills are enabled in my polyfills.ts file:

```
import "core-js/es5";
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

I appreciate any advice you can provide!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have produced a minimal Angular 5 application, that used 1.x of the angular-cli. I have replicated the build behaviour in this which generates the error from UglifyJS also.

You can find the app on my Github [here](https://github.com/parky128/angular-5-cli-es6)

I have seen that UglifyJS used in the version of Webpack the angular-cli uses, does not support es6 transpilation.

Without migrating angular\cli versions, I am interested to see if there is a way to get the sample app compiling for production and functioning without any issues.

**UPDATE 2**

So after some more experimenting, I have concluded that the most graceful way of handling ES6 transpilation when building an Angular 5 app is to use `ng eject` to get the webpack.config.js file and configure the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` as explained in this [article](https://blog.dripstat.com/using-es6-with-webpack-3-in-production/)

This works perfectly fine, and does actually allow more finer grained control over webpack which the angular-cli hides you from initially.

I'm open to other suggestions\answers, so feel free to add here!

I would still love to find a way to use angular-cli if at all possible though.

Comment: Without a source code it is difficult to tell and actually I am not using Angular CLI. For me the issue is a bit odd because as my understanding, all the code will go through Typescript to be transpile to whatever ES version, could be 5 or 6. How come the uglifyjs doesn't support ES6 is the matter.
Anyway, this topic came on top when I searched for the issue (you might probably seen it already) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5741. Have you tried to modified the package.json as the guys mentioned on the post?
`"uglify-js": "github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony"`

Comment: Thanks, yes I came across the fact uglifyJS doesnt support ES6 also, so I think thats my root problem. I dont have uglify-js as a dependency in my package.json, its a dependency of one of the other angular modules (angular-cli) I think, so its not something I can easily change. I am actually now investigating using `ng eject` to extract the webpack config to see if I can change the config to use a different plugin for es6

Comment: Do you have tsconfig.json on your folder? Not sure if angular cli generate it. You can try to modify the target down to ES5 `"target": "es5"`  https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Comment: Mine is already set to target `es5`, it has been since the start of my project

Comment: Would you mind to send me your source code? Just trim a the important part and send the Skeleton one include you custom module. Hopefully I can find something.

Comment: What about `allowJs` option in `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: If you can get at the underlying UglifyJS settings, you can probably use exclude to not run your ES6 code through the UglifyJS plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin Seems like you may have to duplicate the Angular CLI to modify Uglify options, though. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3861

Comment: @JeffryHouser yeah I have been looking at ejecting my app from the cli as this will give me the webpack config file so in theory I can customise to suit my needs. I have not succeeded yet, also uglifyjs will not work for es6, I need to use a different plugin

Comment: @trungk18 - I have just updated my question with a link to a sample app that replicates the behaviour. So if you are still interested in taking a look, then I would appreciate it!

Comment: It may related to the angular-cli version. I can build and serve the git example as production without any problem. The angular-cli that I use 1.6.8

Comment: @SeyhmusGokcen - Thanks, I am also on 1.6.8 however, so that confuses me how you are able to build for production using my repo as is. Are you using the `npm run build` command? Also how are you serving up the prod built sources?

Comment: @mindparse Got it, I am checking now.

Comment: @mindparse Actually I am not use your command, I use sequencially; 1- `ng build --env=prod` 2- `ng serve--env=prod` I just check and log the environment on the app initializing and production is running.

Comment: @mindparse By the way, I got your error when I use the command like you say `npm run build` It may caused by that cli try to run the app when the transpile has not finished. Because I did my commands one by by not at the sametime

Comment: @mindparse And the last one, you should import the environment in the app as `import { environment } from '../environments/environment';`

Comment: @SeyhmusGokcen - the `ng build --env=prod` does not perform any uglification of the source code which is why the compilation completes. So if you look in the browser debugger and the sources, you will see the vendor.bundle.js still contains the ES6 code as is. If you run the `ng build --prod` command which `npm run build` wraps around anyway, then this will attempt to uglify the code, since this flag is what angular-cli is looking out for internally so it knows whether to uglify or not

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to upgrade to the latest Angular version? There you would not have this issue? Angular 5 will go out of support anyway in a few months. Take a look at the [Support policy and schedule](https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule).

Comment: @mindparse yes you are right. I did not check the vendor. I just search it deeply after your comment. I see a command that track the modules which cause the error. I run the `npm build --prod -sm` command because of figuring out which module cause the issue and I see that your @alertlogic module not run as es6. Do you have any chance to convert it to es6? By the way the -sm flag means that --sourcemap

Comment: The `ng eject` command is disabled in latest angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

I can see three options to resolve your problem:

1. Update to the latest Angular version including cli and re-build your project which should be just fine. (optimal option)
2. If for some reason (as your git repo only shows minimal version of the project) you cannot update. You can try `"uglify-js": "github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony"`  it's an es6 friendly version of UglifyJS
3. As you already discovered, you can always eject and fine tune your config (more advanced option)

Comment: Thanks, upgrading angular is certainly the best way. In the meantime, I have opted to write my line in Typescript and compile down to es5 using webpack and Babel. This is working well so far, plus it means I can generate bundles for different module systems to accomadate a wider developer community